# $\chi(n)=\frac{\tau_k(\chi)}{\sqrt k}\sum_{m=1}^k \bar\chi(m)e^{-\frac{2\pi imn}{k}}$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, characters, gauss-sums, dirichlet-character

> [Analytic Number Theory - Florian Luca and Jean Marie De Koninck, chapter 14, question 14.5]
>
> A character is called primitive modulo $k$ if it is not induced from any divisor $d<k$, or in other words, if for every divisor $d$ of $k$, there is a number $a\equiv 1\pmod d$ with $(a,k)=1$ and $\chi(a)\neq 1$. Show that if $\chi$ is primitive modulo $k$, then
> $$\chi(n)=\frac{\tau_k(\chi)}{\sqrt k}\sum_{m=1}^k \bar\chi(m)e^{-\frac{2\pi imn}{k}}$$
> where
> $$\tau_k(\chi)=\frac{G(1,\chi)}{\sqrt k}$$
> if $\chi$ is primitive modulo $k$.

In previous exercises, I had to prove that if
$$G(n,\chi)=\sum_{m=1}^k \chi(m)e^{\frac{2\pi imn}{k}}$$
then assuming $(n,k)=1$, we have
$$G(n,\chi)=\bar\chi(n)G(1,\chi)$$
and
$$|G(1,\chi)|^2 = p$$
where $k=p$ is a prime.

These two are enough to solve the problem for the special case $(n,k)=1$. But, I can't figure out how to deal with the case $(n,k)>1$.

---

**Note:** The initial version of this post was different due to a typo in the original question. The main problem now is in the case $(n,k)>1$. I am sorry for the confusion.

Comment: That totally has to be a typo—the summation should go up to $k$ instead of $n$.

Comment: @GregMartin I just didn't think it can be a typo! I thought, if it's a typo, then there's nothing more to do here! Where exactly are we using the fact that $\chi$ is primitive modulo $k$? The two properties mentioned hold for any character $\chi$ modulo $k$...

Comment: The modulus of the Gauss sum certainly depends on $\chi$ being primitive for general modulus, as does the first exercise when $(n,k)>1$ I believe.

Comment: @GregMartin both of the exercises were proven assuming $(n,k)=1$.

Comment: Note that $(n,k)=1$ is not a hypothesis of the statement you're being asked to prove. The case $(n,k)>1$ is where primitivity is necessary.

Comment: @GregMartin I see... I placed an edit

Comment: @GregMartin can you show me the proof of the case $(n,k)>1$?

Comment: Look in Montgomery/Vaughan's "Multiplicative Number Theory", the section on Gauss sums.

Comment: @GregMartin thanks, I found it there!

Answer (score 1):

This is a typo. To produce an easy counterexample, choose your favorite primitive character and compute some random values. Say, for example, we choose the unique primitive character mod $4$, which we write $\chi_{-4}$ as it has Kronecker symbol $(-4/\cdot)$. This is the character that has $\chi_{-4}(1) = 1$ and $\chi_{-4}(-1) = -1$. Note also that as $1 \equiv -1 \bmod 2$ and as $2$ is the only nontrivial divisor of $4$, $\chi_{-4}$ is primitive.

Let's compute $\chi_{-4}(2) = 0$ according to the given formula,
$$\chi_{-4}(2)=\frac{\tau_2(\chi_{-4})}{2} \bar\chi(1)e^{-\frac{4\pi i}{4}} = \frac{-1}{2} \tau_2(\chi_{-4}) + 0.$$
This is already enough to stop, as the first term on the right is nonzero (as the Gauss sum has size $2$), and this is a contradiction.

The summation should go up to $k$.

Comment: But then, where exactly do we have to use the fact that $\chi$ is primitive modulo $k$? The two properties mentioned in the post hold for any character $\chi$ modulo $k$...

Comment: The question has been changed. I am sorry for the confusion.